# How to disable cache for specific pages dynamically in next js?

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js

I want some posts without caching and some posts with caching.
Each post has a property which tells whether the post should be cached or not e.g. ***post.cached***. I am using ***getServerSideProps*** method to render posts.

**next.config.js**

```
async headers() {
    return [
    {
            source: "/",
            headers: [
              {
                key: "Cache-Control",
                value: "public, max-age=300",
              },
            ],
          },
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Inside `getServerSideProps` method of the pages you want to customize caching

```
Page.getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');

    return {
        props: {}
    };
};
```

2. Via `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  headers: () => [
    {
      // Create glob to target specific pages you want
      source: '/:path*',
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'Cache-Control',
          value: 'no-store',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: The second option won't work as it defines the `Cache-Control` header when the app gets build, not dynamically. For the first option, how can that be made dynamic so it depends on data fetched at runtime (`post.cached` like OP mentioned)?